# Cannot get FindTextualAnswer to work in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: warning-messages

Although `FindTextualAnswer` is flagged as experimental, I still wanted to check it out. The following example from the documentation doesn't evaluate.

```
In[1]:= FindTextualAnswer["Paris is the capital and most populous \
city of France, with a 2015 population of 2,229,621.", "How many \
people live in Paris?"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= FindTextualAnswer::wlnetcorr2: A required WLNet file is corrupted and could not be loaded.

Out[1]= $Failed
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Generally the best route to take here would be to contact support: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical.  What OS are you on?

Comment: It works here. FindTextualAnswer downloads things from a Wolfram database. Is it possible you were operating without an internet connection (in which case the download would fail).

Comment: Worked fine on macOS 10.13.4 but there is a long delay for download of a large database (~500MB).

Comment: @bill s Will retry download and get back

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I am on Windows 10. I retried evaluation in a fresh session. It doesn't start any download like last time but simply throws the same error. Is there a way to force re-download and hence retrieve the possibly missing dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by first deleting the corresponding Wolfram Research data folder(*3df*) in the *Resource* directory located under `$LocalBase`.
[image]

Then I re-evaluated the `FindTextualAnswer` code in the docs. This forced a re-download and fixed the missing dependencies.